# Concatenating strings within EL expression defined in an attribute of a facelets tag

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, el

I need to write an EL expression for an attribute which goes something like this:

```
#{cc.attrs.appreciatedByCurrentUser ? (cc.attrs.count +'<br/>'+ (cc.attrs.count-1)) : ((cc.attrs.count+1) +'<br/>'+ cc.attrs.count)}
```

Now the problem is that this gives an error as strings cannot be concatenated, the way I am doing it. So how can I rectify this?

*I'm using JSF 2.0 with facelets.*

---

### **EDIT :**

I'm resolving the issue using the following inline javascript

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var count=#{cc.attrs.count};
                document.write(#{cc.attrs.appreciatedByCurrentUser} ? (count-1) +'<br/>'+count  : count+'<br/>'+ (count+1));
            </script>
```

Can you think of any issue with this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

String concatenation in EL is only possible by just inlining in the expression. The `+` operator is in EL exclusively a sum operator. Further, `<` and `>` are invalid characters in XML attributes, so you have to escape them (and instruct `<h:outputText>` to not escape them once again by `escape="false"`):

```
<h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.count}&lt;br/&gt;#{cc.attrs.count-1}" escape="false" rendered="#{cc.attrs.appreciatedByCurrentUser}" />
<h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.count+1}&lt;br/&gt;#{cc.attrs.count}" escape="false" rendered="#{!cc.attrs.appreciatedByCurrentUser}" />
```

Alternatively, you can also use `<c:set>` to alias the expression:

```
<c:set var="appreciated" value="#{cc.attrs.count}&lt;br/&gt;#{cc.attrs.count-1}" />
<c:set var="notAppreciated" value="#{cc.attrs.count+1}&lt;br/&gt;#{cc.attrs.count}" />
<h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.appreciatedByCurrentUser ? appreciated : notAppreciated}" escape="false" />
```

Comment: i had this idea in mind but I saw in another answer  by you where you had talked about the performance issues associated with `rendered` attribute(1 ms for each `rendered`) If I implement this using your proposed solution that would add up *atleast* 50 more rendered attributes in my page. Thus 50ms delay..!??

Comment: For pure output components that's really negligible. Anyway, I added an alternative using `ui:param`. With your JavaScript approach, you're only moving the CPU time from server to client side.

Comment: yes, javascript approach doesnt benefit in terms of performance but I just wanted to know(thinking a bit in JavaScript direction), is there any harm from this inline javascript usage., though I like your solution using `ui:param`

Comment: With ui:param it was possible to use concatenated string as key for resource bundle. Anyway, isn't EL pronounciated by Americans as ILL? I don't think it's an accident ;)

Comment: I like the `ui:param` suggestion.  I never had a need for that element until now.

Comment: Just appending them in `ui:param` works for me: `<ui:param name="appreciated" value="#{cc.attrs.count} #{cc.attrs.count-1}" />`. I'm with Mojarra 2.1.26.

Answer (score 69):

It is possible to concatenate Strings in EL using the `java.lang.String.concat(String)` method. Thus your code could look like:

```
<h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.appreciatedByCurrentUser ?  (''.concat(cc.attrs.count).concat('&lt;br/&gt;').concat(cc.attrs.count-1)) :  (''.concat((cc.attrs.count+1)).concat('&lt;br/&gt;').concat(cc.attrs.count))}" escape="false" />
```

In this particular case however I would go with one of the options that Mr BalusC had suggested because the code above doesn't look quite elegant. In some cases knowing this technique could be useful, though.

I would hardly recommend using javascript as a workaround here.

Comment: Note that this requires EL 2.2.

Comment: @Fritz: EL is not part of JSF. It's part of the server. You can even use JSF 1.x on EL 2.2.

Comment: I see, @BalusC how can you check if a certain server uses which EL? I'm using Websphere 8.5, Java EE 6

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing i can come up with.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{cc.attrs.appreciatedByCurrentUser}">
   <h:outputText value="#{(cc.attrs.count)}" style="display:block;" />
   <h:outputText value="#{(cc.attrs.count-1)}" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not cc.attrs.appreciatedByCurrentUser}">
   <h:outputText value="#{(cc.attrs.count+1)}" style="display:block;" />
   <h:outputText value="#{(cc.attrs.count)}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Putting `<br>` in a value attribute will always throw errors in JSF, so you'll have to use `display:block`.

Comment: Or you could add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`
and write `<h:outputText /><br /><h:outputText />`