# Concatenating strings in EL

Tags: jsf, el

The following keeps returning null any idea why

```
<ui:param name="dialogName" value="#{index.toString().concat('Overlay')}" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do this:

```
<ui:param name="dialogName" value="#{cc.attrs.xProd.product.productId}Overlay" />
```

See also:

- [Concatenating Strings within EL expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386133/concatenating-strings-within-el-expression-defined-in-an-attribute-of-a-facelets)