# Put linebreak/newline in tooltip

Tags: jsf, tooltip, newline

I'd like to put a linebreak in a tooltip so that it displays like:

> Nom: value1
>   Quality: value2

I tried:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302236/concatenating-strings-in-el/11302880#11302880).

```
<h:outputText title="Nom: #{cntc.value1}&lt;br/&gt;Quality: #{cntc.value1}" />
```

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386133/concatenating-strings-within-el-expression-defined-in-an-attribute-of-a-facelets).

```
<h:outputText title="Nom: #{ (''.concat(cntc.value1).concat('&lt;br/&gt;')concat('Quality: ').concat(cntc.value2)}" />
```

None of them worked for me. It seems that the `<br/>` isn't being interpreted.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "none of them worked for me"? You did nowhere describe the actual problem. Do you mean to say that the `<br>` is not being interpreted and shown plain vanilla? Don't you actually mean to ask how to get a linebreak in a HTML tooltip rather than how to concatenate strings in EL which you already have figured out for long? But why did you show `value1 value2` without linebreak in the question example? This whole question is vague and confusing.

Comment: Excuse me @BalusC, but as you expected I got an exception with `<br>` not interpreted, just as you wrote it, I didn't get any response quickly, so I simplified the question to only separating the two values, my bad, but the original question is this linebreak  and concatenating the values with labels, if you are suggesting, as @Makhil did, that I should change the address, I will be glad to do, Thanks.

Comment: You would have had exactly the same problem when using hardcoded values in tooltip instead of EL expressions. You would have had exactly the same problem when hardcoding HTML output instead of producing it with JSF.

Comment: Knowing that you'd just have searched for ["how to put linebreak/newline in tooltip"](https://google.com/search?q=how%20to%20put%20linebreak%20newline%20in%20tooltip) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good idea to name the problem "Concatenating strings in EL" if your issue is with neither of those things. You want to create a multi-line title, that's an HTML problem.

Title only accepts text so `<br/>` will not work but you can put a line break (`&#13;`) in there:

```
<h:outputText value="#{cntc.mail }" title="Nom: #{cntc.nom}&#13;Qualite: #{cntc.qualite}" />
```

Note that this may not work in every browser.