# Multiple EL values and strings used with a single HTML attribute

Tags: html, jsf, el

In my .xhtml pages in my JSF 2.0 application, I am trying to find out a way to have multiple EL values and strings to be used with a single HTML attribute. The following WRONG syntax will give you the idea:

```
<h:outputText value=" 'Welcome' + #{myBean.loggedInUser} + ' '  "/>
```

So I am wondering what is the correct way of doing it. I don't need a workaround (as h:outputText is just an example).

Also let me know if your suggestion works in JSP/JSF1.2 or not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenating strings within EL expression defined in an attribute of a facelets tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386133/concatenating-strings-within-el-expression-defined-in-an-attribute-of-a-facelets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any special operators. You can just inline EL in text.

```html
<h:outputText value="Welcome #{myBean.loggedInUser}" />
```

or

```html
Welcome <h:outputText value="#{myBean.loggedInUser}" />
```

or even in template text

```html
Welcome #{myBean.loggedInUser}
```

Comment: I am looking to have something like the first one, but mine doesn't work.
Second and third option does work, but as I said outputText is an example. The actual code contains more complex tags.

Comment: You're welcome. In the future, post an SSCCE instead of oversimplified code which doesn't accurately represent the actual code.

Answer (score -1):

The `<h:outputFormat>` component?

http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputFormat.html

I believe that is either JSF 1.2 or 2

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a request-scoped bean that handles the concatenation / construction of the attribute's value as method output.  Then call the method within the xhtml.

Comment: Do not try to mix view logic with business logic or server side logic. If you do that, you're breaking the MVC pattern.